# Reading CLOB in before insert,update trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, clob

I am trying to create a before insert & update trigger on a table in Oracle.
While am trying to read the NEW.CLOB_COLUMN_VALUE, its giving me blank.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TEST101
(
  ID               NUMBER(2),
  TEST_CLOB_VALUE  CLOB
)
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_Temp_Test101
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON Temp_Test101 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN

If (:NEW.TEST_CLOB_VALUE = 'A')
Then
    raise_application_error(-20010,'Testing Successfull');
End IF;

raise_application_error(-20010,'Testing Failed:['||:NEW.TEST_CLOB_VALUE||']');


END TR_Temp_Test101;
/
```

Prompt after trying to insert :

```
ORA-20010: Testing Failed:[]
```

Is there any way we can read the `:NEW.TEST_CLOB_VALUE` before insert/update?

The requirement is to validate the data of the CLOB column before insert/update.

Comment: That seems to work fine. - inserting an A gets 'successful[A]', inserting B gets [failed[B]'. You haven't shown the insert statement you used though - what is the actual value you're trying to insert?

Comment: I always use rowid to add records.. Insert query works just fine. : select rowid,t1.* from Temp_Test101 t1

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply & correction. When adding using rowid the prompt shows empty []. However when using insert statement the trigger is working properly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you're inserting by selecting existing values? That query would give you too many columns for your table... Also which version of Oracle are you using, in case that's relevant?

Comment: @AlexPoole. Its pretty clear he is trying to compare a clob with a single character. There might be the case that clob is having some blank spaces and its not getting evaluated.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g. Let me explain in detail. If you run the query "select rowid,t1.* from Temp_Test101 t1" in toad for oracle. You can modify the records directly from the grid[display]. In this case the prompt is showing empty [] when I try to display the CLOB value. In TOAD by using rowid in the query we can modify the result set directly. Please check :https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/b/weblog/archive/2011/07/20/row-row-rowid-your-record-gently-update-the-table

Comment: Well, that's a fairly important detail, since it works fine as-is with a straightforward insert or update statement (e.g. from SQL\*Plus).

Comment: Yes sir! That's why i got confused initially! However as you pointed out that with a straightforward insert or update it works out perfectly. Anyway i closed the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks :) Just looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a `clob` column you need to check the condition as

```
dbms_lob.substr(:NEW.TEST_CLOB_VALUE,1,1) = 'A'
```

See demo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_Temp_Test101
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON Temp_Test101
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   IF (dbms_lob.substr(:NEW.TEST_CLOB_VALUE,1,1) = 'A')
   THEN
      raise_application_error (-20010, 'Testing Successfull');
   END IF;

   raise_application_error (
      -20010,
      'Testing Failed:[' || :NEW.TEST_CLOB_VALUE || ']');
END TR_Temp_Test101;
```

Execution:

```
SQL> Insert into TEMP_TEST101 values(1,'A');
Insert into TEMP_TEST101 values(1,'A')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20010: Testing Successfull
ORA-06512: at "TR_TEMP_TEST101", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TR_TEMP_TEST101'
```

Comment: The OP seems to want to compare the whole value, not just the first character? Comparing a CLOB with a CLOB works, as does comparing a CLOB with a string literal up to a point - until the 32k string literal limit is reached.

Comment: I checked his example code. It doesnot look like he wants to compare the whole clob and thats not possible as well.